# Consume data from Kafka topic with a huge lag

Tags: apache-kafka, erlang

I'm facing an issue with Kafka topic consumption from a topic with lag.

Here are some details:

- I'm using erlang brod client with group id
- I have several consumers in the same group (3 to 5)
- If my consumers crash or being disconnected for a while there's going to be a huge lag for it's group id (we're talking about ~150 millions messages per day)
- If I restart consumers keeping it's group id I can see a small drop in lag, but then lag keeps growing as if there's no consumers
- From consumers metrics I can see that number of consumed messages gets stuck eventually
  I don't understand why this is happening. If I restart consumers with different group id they are going to consume data starting from the latest messages and they are able to keep up with producing rate (meaning, there's no significant lag)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are

1. Run more consumers, up to the number of partitions
2. consume, process and commit in smaller batches assuming that it can work faster than data comes from the producer
3. increase the batch sizes of the producer(s) to send the same data, but not as frequent